# how to handling events 'Tab Control' with multiple child form

Tags: c++, mfc

I see "[Simple Tab Control For Visual C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8565/Simple-Tab-Control-For-Visual-C)" in codeproject and this project not handled events on other form, I try with [OnChildNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyyskx80.aspx) to fix it but not work.
How can i hanlded this events?(Please fix code project source code)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`OnChildNotify` is useful if you are subclassing the tab control. You can also use `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT` for subclass (use one or the other).

For a simple example, you don't need the above codeproject example, you can just use `CTabCtrl`. And you can process messages from parent window by adding `ON_NOTIFY` to message map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialogEx)
   ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB1, OnTabSelChange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDialog::OnTabSelChange(NMHDR*, LRESULT*)
{
    //user changed tab index
    //new index = Tab.GetCurSel()
}
```

In this example, `CMyDialog` can have multiple child windows.

See also [Tab Control Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, I try OnChildNotify and ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT (with NM_CLICK,WM_BUTTONPRESSED,TCN_SELCHANGE, etc) in main class and subclass form on codeproject but not work. only TCN_SELCHANGE handle tab changed but not handled other object in tab control for ex. button clicked,please see code project src and fix it.

Comment: I need have a multiple form for easy form designing and handling events otherwise single form working aright.

Comment: Use `ON_NOTIFY` in main class, it doesn't need anything else. Use either `OnChildNotify` OR `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT` in subclass. Don't use all of them at once.